# How to get the type of a variable so I can call a turbofish function?

Tags: generics, types, rust

Sometimes I have a variable, and I want to call a 'turbofish' function with the variable's type.  For example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let arr = [0u8; 4];
    println!("size_of arr: {}", std::mem::size_of::< TYPE_OF(arr) >());
}
```

Of course, `TYPE_OF()` doesn't exist.  So I end up having to hard-code the type manually:

```rust
println!("size_of arr: {}", std::mem::size_of::< [u8;4] >());
```

It sure would be nice if I could get the type of a variable (at compile-time, not runtime) so I didn't need to hard-code the type myself.

Comment: Your specific example can be handled by `std::mem::size_of_val(&arr)`. And I would bet there's a better alternative for most other examples you can think of.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley this should be the answer. As Rust infers the type when it's possible, there's no point in a vague question, there are only rare specific cases to handle, like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your particular example, there is already a function in `std` to get the size of a type, based on its value; `std::mem::size_of_val`:

```
println!("size_of arr: {}", std::mem::size_of_val(&arr));
```

In general, if you want to bind a type variable to a type, you probably need to do it in the body of a function. For example, if `size_of_val` did not exist, you could do:

```
fn main() {
    fn size_of_val<T>(_: &T) -> usize {
        std::mem::size_of::<T>()
    }
    let arr = [0u8; 4];
    println!("size_of arr: {}", size_of_val(&arr));
}
```